# How can make a cache class in android?

Tags: java, android, json, caching

I am building an articles reading android application like TechChurn. I am fetching data from server in the form of json.

I am parsing title, author name and articles-content from json and displaying it in list-view.

This loaded article are save in my local file and are loaded in my application when there is no internet access.

This i have done using a cache class.

Now suppose i have load 50 articles in my app and my app is in online mode means there is internet services now i open my app one's again in offline mode means no internet services the data is cached and show 50 articles from local cache file.

Now the problem that i face is that if my app is open one's again in online mode.
It load 10 articles in initially stated and this 10 articles are been copy past in local file from previous 50 articles and now the local file has only 10 articles.

which means that if i run my app in offline mode now.

It will show only 10 article because that 50 articles are been loaded by 10 articles.
Here is my cache class -

```
package cache;
public class CacheThis {

private void CacheThis() {}

public static void writeObject(Context context, String fileName, Object object) throws      
 IOException {
      FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      oos.writeObject(object);
      oos.flush();
      oos.close();

      fos.close();
   }

   public static Object readObject(Context context, String fileName) throws IOException,
         ClassNotFoundException {
      FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      Object object = ois.readObject();
      fis.close();
      return object;
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case better to use database for save data for offline mode. I preferred ORMLite:
http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml
In that case you don't need to open and read file, parse json every time for every item. And tou will work with object model, not with raw json.

Comment: I dont want to load data every time. i need that when any new article is parse during internet access that particular article move to the local file where i am storing all rest articles.